# How to customize color scheme to mimic that in Origin?

Tags: plotting, color

[Origin](http://www.originlab.com/) is a software for plotting.

The standard color scheme used by Origin is

[image: Origin colormap]

So how do I mimic this color scheme in *Mathematica*, so that we can use it in `DensityPlot` to achieve the same appearance that will be produced by Origin?

---

**edit**

C. E. already provided a color bar that resembles the one in Origin.

To use it in `ListDensityPlot`, there is one more step needed to specify the `ColorFunction` properly:

```
DensityPlot[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 ColorFunction -> (Hue[1 - (2 #/3 + 1/3)] &), 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

Notice that I use 1/3, because in Origin, the color runs from blue to red. Red corresponds to `Hue[1]` and blue corresponds to `Hue[1/3]`. This can be seen from `ColorConvert[Hue[1/3], RGBColor] // FullForm`. (Thanks to J.M. for letting me know about `ColorConvert`)

The above code gives

[image: density plot]

Comment: It's very similar to `Hue`: `BarLegend[{Hue[1 - #] &, {0.3, 1}}]`

Comment: @Pickett Bravo! indeed. Make it answer? or is it a duplicate? or just too trivial : )

Comment: Have a look at `BarLegend[{Hue[2 (1 - Rescale[#, {-1, 1}])/3] &, {-1, 1}}]`.

Comment: @J.M. Thank you. A question: How to know the RGB values of for example `Hue[0.33]`?

Comment: You can use `ColorConvert[]` to convert colors in any other format to RGB; e.g. `ColorConvert[Hue[1/3], RGBColor]`.

Comment: @J.M. Thank you very much ! I have corrected my post. Now it should be exactly the same as Origin

Comment: This is pretty similar to the [Jet color map](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/101625/9490) from MATLAB.  Jet goes a little darker in the red and blue than the examples using `Hue`

Comment: The `Hue[]` version is preferable, but otherwise, here's a `Blend[]` version: `Blend[{Blue, Cyan, Green, Yellow, Red}, #] &`.

Comment: @J.M. Sorry for the late reply. This is great! Make it an answer? : )

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is basically a reversed `Hue` that's been clipped off. In the image to the left below you see all of the values of `Hue` next to one that I cut off by picking a value (0.3) that seemed right. That value could be calculated more rigorously by looking at the color peaks and the distances between them in the Origin bar legend.

```
Row[{
  BarLegend[{Hue[1 - #] &, {0, 1}}],
  BarLegend[{Hue[1 - #] &, {0.3, 1}}]
  }]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Since `Hue[2/3]` is actually `Blue` after RGB conversion, your second line should be something like `BarLegend[{Hue[2 (1 - #)/3] &, {0, 1}}]`.

Answer (score 6):

By request:

Altho I prefer the `Hue[]` formulation:

```
originColorFunction = Hue[2 (1 - #)/3] &;
```

one can also choose to implement this in terms of `Blend[]`:

```
originColorFunction2 = Blend[{Blue, Cyan, Green, Yellow, Red}, #] &;
```

To see why this works, recall that in the HSB system, the color cycle proceeds in the sequence `Red`, `Yellow`, `Green`, `Cyan`, `Blue`, `Magenta`, and finally back to `Red`, with linear interpolation of colors in between:

```
ColorConvert[Hue /@ (Range[0, 5]/6), RGBColor]
   {RGBColor[1., 0., 0.], RGBColor[1., 1., 0.], RGBColor[0., 1., 0.],
    RGBColor[0., 1., 1.], RGBColor[0., 0., 1.], RGBColor[1., 0., 1.]}
```

and since the Origin color function has `Magenta` dropped, as well as the colors being reversed, the simple linear interpolation with `Blend[]` will produce the exact same color sequence.

Comment: (N.B. this is also the color scheme used by the [DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/help/vrml/aboutcolor#S1).)