# ContourPlot with custom ColorFunction: Odd behavior of "Contours" option?

Tags: plotting, color

I am trying to generate a blue-cyan-green-yellow-red color gradient that is linear in Hue.  The code

```
ContourPlot[x, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, ContourStyle -> None, 
ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Hue[2/3*(1 - x)]], 
ColorFunctionScaling -> False, AspectRatio -> 0.125, 
ImageSize -> 840]
```

gives

[image: ContoursDefault]
<sub>(source: [ucdavis.edu](https://bme.ucdavis.edu/heinrichlab/files/2016/06/ContoursDefault.png))</sub>

which seems okay.  However, adding the option `Contours -> 500` to the above, i.e., evaluating

```
ContourPlot[x, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, Contours -> 500, 
ContourStyle -> None, 
ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Hue[2/3*(1 - x)]], 
ColorFunctionScaling -> False, AspectRatio -> 0.125, 
ImageSize -> 840]
```

produces

[image: Contours500]
<sub>(source: [ucdavis.edu](https://bme.ucdavis.edu/heinrichlab/files/2016/06/Contours500.png))</sub>

By trying different numbers for Contours, I can reduce the odd artifact at the red end of this gradient.  But I suspect I am missing something.  Any suggestions?  Thanks a lot.

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with the custom `ColorFunction`, but with whatever internal function decides on the contour levels.  Just look at the output from `ContourPlot[x, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, Contours -> 60]`....

Comment: I see this bug as far back as version 9, as well as the current versions.  A workaround is to supply the contour levels manually, via something like `Contours -> Subdivide[500]`

Comment: JasonB, thanks a lot for the quick response!  "Subdivide" does what I need, and your reply ended several days of agony for me ...

Comment: So you would think that the contour levels chosen automatically would correspond to `(1.0/61  Range[60])` when `Contours -> 60` is chosen.  But instead, the contours correspond to `Round[1/61, .001] Range[60]`...... Bug report filed

Comment: my eyes must be going.. what artifact are we supposed to see here?

Comment: @george2079. The solid-color red rectangle on the right side of the second image. The colors aren't continuous there. (It actually is pretty subtle.)

Comment: I see.. You can see this more clearly if you do `ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Hue[RandomReal[]]]` . I'm not sure this is a bug though, if you consider that you don't typically have an iso-line exactly on the boundary of a contour plot, `ContourPlot`'s spacing algorithm maybe doesn't try to  make the boundary bands equal spaced.  (The left end is slightly wider too..)

Comment: The band is much starker when you use `GrayLevel`: `ContourPlot[x, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, AspectRatio -> 0.125, ColorFunction -> GrayLevel, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, Contours -> 500, ContourStyle -> None, ImageSize -> 840]`

Comment: There's still a problem with much fewer contours: `ContourPlot[x, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, AspectRatio -> 0.125, ColorFunction -> GrayLevel, Contours -> 5]`

Comment: I observe the same behavior with version 8.0.4.

Comment: As for the coloring scheme itself, [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/101268) is a related thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is easy to see what is happening if you leave out `ContourStyle -> None`.  For some reason [`ContourPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot.html) does not automatically select contours near to maximum value in the plot.  Some `Contour` values are worse than others in this regard.  A solution is to specify contours manually.

```
ContourPlot[x, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}
 , ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Hue[2/3*(1 - x)]]
 , ColorFunctionScaling -> False
 , AspectRatio -> 0.125
 , ImageSize -> 640
 , Contours -> #
] & /@ {76, Subdivide[1, 76]} // Column
```

[image]