# Is that possible to remove a color from Hue spectrum?

Tags: plotting, color

I have checked all Mathematica color schemes, and I think "Hue" is the most vibrant, beautiful one. However, it has one issue: the two ends of the spectrum are red (though, different reds). I like a spectrum from, say, red to blue. Is that possible to manipulate the Hue and remove the pink and second red?

Consider the following:

```
DensityPlot[Sin[x y], {x, 0.1, 1}, {y, 0.1, 1}, PlotLegends -> Automatic, Frame -> True, ColorFunction -> Hue]
```

The output is 
[image]

As you see, the two extremes are red.

Comment: I would look at the `Blend` function: `Function@Blend[{Red, Yellow, Green, Cyan, Blue}, #]` can be passed as a color function that will go from red to blue; alternately, I often pass `(Hue[0.67*(1 - #)]&)` as a color function argument when I want the color to vary from blue (low values) to red (high values).

Answer (score 2):

Your question looks almost a duplicate of this one:

- [How to customize color scheme to mimic that in Origin?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/101268/280)

Using the formulation from the [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/101933/280) by [J.M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/j-m) we get:

```
DensityPlot[Sin[x y], {x, 0.1, 1}, {y, 0.1, 1}, PlotLegends -> Automatic, Frame -> True, 
 ColorFunction -> (Hue[2 (1 - #)/3] &)]
```

> [image: plot]

Answer (score 1):

From [Documentation >> Hue >> Details](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Hue.html)

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So, we need to rescale the function values (that run from `-1` to `1`)  to the unit interval:

```
DensityPlot[Sin[x y], {x, 0.1, 1}, {y, 0.1, 1}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, Frame -> True, 
 ColorFunction -> (Hue[Rescale[#, {-1, 1}, {0, 1}]] &)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or, using the option ColorFunctionScaling -> False:

```
DensityPlot[Sin[x y], {x, 0.1, 1}, {y, 0.1, 1}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, Frame -> True, ColorFunction -> Hue, 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I tested this, but it works only for simple functions like sin(xy). I'm supposed to draw a plot of a very complicated function. Unfortunately, this approach did not work.