# Independent Colorfunction in RevolutionPlot3D

Tags: plotting

probably a trivial questions, but I couldn't find a solution for over 2 hours:

I want to produce a RevolutionPlot3D of a function, f1, with a separate colorfunction, f2.
I thought it might be possible to specify something like:

```
RevolutionPlot3D[r^2*Sin[2*\[Theta]], {r, 0, 1}, {\[Theta], 0, 2*Pi}, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, r1, \[Theta]1}, ColorData["Rainbow"][Abs[z]]]]
```

where

```
f1 = r^2*Sin[2*\[Theta]]
```

and

```
f2 = Abs[r^2*Sin[2*\[Theta]]]
```

but I got this
[image]

instead of the expected outcome that should look like this:
[image]

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Bottom plot is not  rainbow see this https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/101268/how-to-customize-color-scheme-to-mimic-that-in-origin

Comment: Based on @Okkes's comment: `RevolutionPlot3D[r^2 Sin[2 θ], {r, 0, 1}, {θ, 0, 2 π}, ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, r, θ}, Hue[2 (1 - Abs[r^2 Sin[2 θ]])/3]], ColorFunctionScaling -> False, Mesh -> False]`

Comment: Just add `ColorFunctionScaling -> False` to your original plot.

Comment: @J.M. - recommend that you also increase the `PlotPoints`

Comment: Thanks a lot, Rahul! It finally clicked and I understand the comment now. Thanks J.M. & Dulgerci - I wouldn't have spotted it.
Problem solved (in case you want to post it as an answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To settle this:

```
RevolutionPlot3D[r^2 Sin[2 θ], {r, 0, 1}, {θ, 0, 2 π}, 
                 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, r, θ}, 
                                           Hue[2 (1 - Abs[r^2 Sin[2 θ]])/3]], 
                 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, Mesh -> False, PlotPoints -> 75]
```

[image: colored saddle]

where I used the color scheme featured [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/101268).